# Compute $\frac1{(2\pi)^{2} }\int d^2p \ e^{-l^2|p|^2}e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}$

Tags: integration

I need compute the integral

$$\frac1{(2\pi)^{2} }\int d^2p \ e^{-l^2|p|^2}e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}$$

The problem does not specified the limits of integration

The result should be

$$\frac{\exp(-x^2/(4l^2))}{4\pi l^2} $$

I have tried using

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^\infty dp p e^{-l^2p^2} e^{ipx \cos (\theta)} $$

But mathematica delivers a Erfi function

Comment: The limits extend over the 2-D space.

Comment: Not sure how useful this question will be to the site, as the question boils down to finding what the author of a book (or something like that) meant to write

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\ell^2 (p_x^2+p_y^2)}e^{i(p_xx+p_yy)}\,dp_x\,dp_y=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\ell^2 p_x^2}e^{ip_xx}\,dp_x\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\ell^2 p_y^2}e^{ip_yy}\,dp_y$$

Also, we have

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\ell^2 p_x^2}e^{ip_xx}\,dp_x&=e^{-x^2/4\ell^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\ell^2(p_x-ix/2\ell^2)^2}\,dp_x\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac\pi{|\ell|}}e^{-x^2/4\ell^2}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\ell^2 (p_x^2+p_y^2)}e^{i(p_xx+p_yy)}\,dp_x\,dp_y=\frac{\pi e^{-(x^2+y^2)/\ell^2}}{\ell^2}$$

And you can finish now.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: And please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)